# How to filter a raster layer and plot only the cells above a certain value in R using Leaflet?

Tags: r, filter, leaflet, subset, raster

I have a raster layer that contains 24-hour snow accumulations across the United States.  The data can be pulled from here:
https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall_v2/data/202105/sfav2_CONUS_24h_2021052412.tif

I only want to plot the cells in the raster with values greater than or equal to 4 (inches) on a leaflet map.  This is what my current map looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mi4r.png

I changed all values less than 4 to NA thinking that the raster cells wouldn't show up on the map.  I want to remove all cells on the map that are greyed-out.  The functions subset() and filter() do not work on raster layers.  Any ideas?  My code below for reference:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

download.file(obsvSnow_Link, destfile = file.path(folderpath, 'observedSnow.tif'))
obsvSnow <- raster(file.path(folderpath, 'observedSnow.tif'))
names(obsvSnow) <- 'snowfall'

obsvSnow[obsvSnow < 4,] <- NA 
          
colores <- c("transparent","#99CCFF","#3399FF","#0000FF","#FFE066", "#FF9900", "#E06666","#CC0000","#990033")
at <- c(4,8,seq(12,42,6),100)
cb <- colorBin(palette = colores, bins = at, domain = at)
          
mp <- leaflet(width = "100%",options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addRasterImage(x=obsvSnow$snowfall, 
                           colors = cb, 
                           opacity = 0.6) %>%
          addLegend(title = 'Inches',
                    position='bottomright',
                    pal = cb, values = at) %>%
          leaflet.extras::addSearchUSCensusBureau(options = searchOptions(autoCollapse=TRUE, minLength=10)) %>%
          addScaleBar(position='bottomleft') %>%
          addFullscreenControl()
          
mp
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. That is, use some data that ships with R, or that you create with code.

Comment: Try `cb <- colorBin(palette = colores, bins = at, domain = at, na.color = 'transparent')`. That way, instead of grey, the NA values will be transparent.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that the na.color = 'transparent' should do the trick.